# How to set up a SwapChain1 for 2D rendering in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

So I've been using `SharpDX`, a C# `DirectX` wrapper to program in `Direct3D11` and `Direct2D`, to draw to a `RenderForm` window in my program. However the `SwapChain.Present` information states I should use a `SwapChain1.Present1` instead and I cannot figure out how to change my code to work with `SwapChain1`. The `CreateWithSwapChain` method in `Device` and even `Device1` only works with a normal `SwapChain` and I don't know how else to simply setup this up.

These are the namespaces being used.

```
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using Factory = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory;
using Resource = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Resource;
```

And this is the code I'm using to setup the `RenderTarget`.

```
SwapChainDescription desc = new SwapChainDescription() {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(
               DXWindow.GetWindow().ClientSize.Width,
               DXWindow.GetWindow().ClientSize.Height,
               new Rational(60, 1),
               Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = DXWindow.GetWindow().Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };
            Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, new SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel[] { SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_10_0 }, desc, out Device device, out swapchain);
            Texture2D backbuffer = Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapchain, 0);
            RenderTargetView renderview = new RenderTargetView(device, backbuffer);
            renderView = new RenderTarget(new Factory(), backbuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>(), new RenderTargetProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
            RenderLoop.Run(DXWindow.GetWindow(), CoreLoop);
```

`DXWindow.GetWindow()` get returns a `RenderForm` and `CoreLoop` is the render loop where I make `Draw` calls and `Present`. How do I use `SwapChain1` instead of `SwapChain` in this?

Comment: What about [this](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/SharpDX.DXGI/SwapChain1/-/php-swapchain1-class-examples.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I've posted my code that works for Swapchain2.  You can interchange the queryinterface with SwapChain1 where needed.  I've included code for Windows Forms and UWP initialisation.  I am not sure which one you are doing here.  So the #define allows you to swap, although I havent done much more work on UWP and it may of been broken since I last touched it.

// Function Create()

```
DXGI.Device1 dxgiDevice1_ = _d3dDevice.QueryInterface<DXGI.Device1>();
DXGI.Adapter dxgiAdapter_ = dxgiDevice1_.Adapter;
DXGI.Factory2 dxgiFactory2_ = dxgiAdapter_.GetParent<DXGI.Factory2>();

ReleaseAllDeviceContexts(true);

if (_swapChain != null)
{
    _swapChain.Dispose();
}

if (_swapChainBuffer != null)
{
    _swapChainBuffer.Dispose();
}

if (_parentSwapchain != null)
{
    _parentSwapchain.Dispose();
}

#if !WINDOWS_UWP
DXGI.SwapChainDescription1 swapChainDescription_ = new DXGI.SwapChainDescription1()
{
    AlphaMode = DXGI.AlphaMode.Ignore,
    Width = _modeDescription.Width,
    Height = _modeDescription.Height,
    Format = DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    Scaling = DXGI.Scaling.None,
    BufferCount = _swapChainBufferCount,
    SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.FlipDiscard,

    Flags = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch,
    Usage = DXGI.Usage.BackBuffer | DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    SampleDescription = new DXGI.SampleDescription() { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
    Stereo = false,
};

_parentSwapchain1 = new DXGI.SwapChain1(dxgiFactory2_, _d3dDevice, _parentContainer.WindowHandle, ref swapChainDescription_, new DXGI.SwapChainFullScreenDescription()
{
    RefreshRate = _modeDescription.RefreshRate,
    Scaling = SharpDX.DXGI.DisplayModeScaling.Unspecified,
    Windowed = isFullscreen == false,
    ScanlineOrdering = DXGI.DisplayModeScanlineOrder.Unspecified,
}
);

_swapChain = _parentSwapchain.QueryInterface<DXGI.SwapChain2>();
#else
DXGI.SwapChainDescription1 swapChainDescription = new DXGI.SwapChainDescription1()
{
    AlphaMode = DXGI.AlphaMode.Ignore,
    Width = _modeDescription.Width,
    Height = _modeDescription.Height,
    Format = DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    Scaling = DXGI.Scaling.Stretch,
    BufferCount = _swapChainBufferCount,
    SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.FlipDiscard,

    Flags = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch | DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowTearing,


    Usage = DXGI.Usage.BackBuffer | DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    SampleDescription = new DXGI.SampleDescription() { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
    Stereo = false,
};

ComObject obj = new ComObject(_parentContainer.WindowHandle);

 _parentSwapchain1 = new DXGI.SwapChain1(dxgiFactory3, _device, ref swapChainDescription, null);

_swapChain2 = _parentSwapchain1.QueryInterface<DXGI.SwapChain2>();

using (DXGI.ISwapChainPanelNative nativeObject = ComObject.As<DXGI.ISwapChainPanelNative>(_parentContainer.WindowHandle))
{
    // Set its swap chain.
    nativeObject.SwapChain = _swapChain2;
}
#endif

_swapChainBuffer = D3D11.Texture2D.FromSwapChain<D3D11.Texture2D>(_swapChain, 0);

dxgiDevice1_.Dispose();
dxgiAdapter_.Dispose();
dxgiFactory2_.Dispose();
```

The resize of the buffer is also included in here for reference as well.  Ignore some of the custom code though, its all internal my game, so some of this wont make sense.

```
           public void ResizeBuffers(bool isFullscreen)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_swapChainBuffer != null)
                {
                    //      if (_parentSwapchain1.IsFullScreen != isFullscreen)
                    {
                        ReleaseAllDeviceContexts(true);

                        SharpDX.Utilities.Dispose(ref _swapChain2);
                        SharpDX.Utilities.Dispose(ref _swapChainBuffer);

#if !WINDOWS_UWP
                        _parentSwapchain1.IsFullScreen = isFullscreen;

                        _parentSwapchain1.ResizeBuffers(0, _modeDescription.Width, _modeDescription.Height, DXGI.Format.Unknown, SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch);
                        if (isFullscreen)
                        {
                            _parentSwapchain1.ResizeTarget(ref _modeDescription);
                        }
#else
                        _parentSwapchain1.ResizeBuffers(0, _modeDescription.Width, _modeDescription.Height, DXGI.Format.Unknown, DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowTearing);
#endif

                        _swapChain2 = _parentSwapchain1.QueryInterface<DXGI.SwapChain2>();

                        _swapChainBuffer = D3D11.Texture2D.FromSwapChain<D3D11.Texture2D>(_swapChain2, 0);
                    }
                    _renderViewport = new Viewport(0, 0, _modeDescription.Width, _modeDescription.Height);
                    _d3dDevice.ImmediateContext1.Rasterizer.SetViewport(_renderViewport);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler.DoErrorHandling(ex, ErrorHandler.GetCurrentMethod(ex));
            }

        }
```